# How can I move the namespace definition from the root element to a specific child in JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, namespaces, jaxb, marshalling

I am developing a Java application that marshals Java objects into XMLs using JAXB. Currently, the generated XML looks like the following one:

```
<A xmlns="A" xmlns:ns2="B" xmlns:ns3="C">
<t1>content</t1>
<t2>
    <ns2:t3>
        <ns2:t4>content2</ns2:t4>           
    </ns2:t3>       
</t2>
</A>
```

The namespace definitions are placed in the root tag "A". Moreover, some of the namespaces (such as "C") are not even used. I would like to place the namespace definitions in the inner child in place of the prefix. For example, I would like to obtain the following xml:

```
<A xmlns="A">
<t1>content</t1>
<t2 xmlns:ns2="B">
    <t3>
        <t4>content2</t4>           
    </t3>       
</t2>
</A>
```

Both of the xmls are valid, but I need to produce the second output in order to pass the validation of a third-party application.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `xmlns:name="..."` only associates a namespace with a prefix. Any element with this prefix will belong to the associated namespace. Elements without prefix belong to the default namespace.

Thus ...

- In your first example namespace C is never used.
- In your second example the only namespace used is the default one, because neither element has a prefix.

Aside from that it doesn't matter where you put your namespace declarations, as long as they are being declared when you need them.

```
<A xmlns="A" xmlns:ns2="B">
<t1>content</t1>
<t2>
    <ns2:t3>
        <ns2:t4>content2</ns2:t4>           
    </ns2:t3>       
</t2>
</A>
```

is equivalent to

```
<A xmlns="A">
<t1>content</t1>
<t2>
    <ns2:t3 xmlns:ns2="B">
        <ns2:t4>content2</ns2:t4>           
    </ns2:t3>       
</t2>
</A>
```

When using JAXB you will have to define the namespaces with the XmlElement-annotations:

```
@XmlElement(name = "t3", namespace = "B")
protected T3 t3;
```

Repeat this for any other element that should belong to this namespace.

## Edit

I tried to recreate the problem with two schemas and a test XML file:

Schema 1

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:b="http://karsten/B"
           targetNamespace="http://karsten/B"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
           
    <xs:complexType name="Wrapper">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Child" type="b:Child"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    
    <xs:complexType name="Child">
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer"/>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

and Schema 2

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:b="http://karsten/B">

    <xs:import schemaLocation="namespaces-experiment-core.xsd" namespace="http://karsten/B"/>
    
    <xs:element name="Root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Wrapper" type="b:Wrapper"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

This XML document validates against the Schema successfully although the namespace of the Child-elements is declared at root level. It's still valid if its moved to the Child-element.

```
<Root xmlns:b="http://karsten/B"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="namespaces-experiment-wrapper.xsd"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://karsten/B namespaces-experiment-core.xsd"
   >
   
    <Wrapper>
        <b:Child id="1"/>
    </Wrapper>
    
</Root>
```

Comment: I already tried specifying the namespace in the `@XmlElement` annotation but JAXB places the xmlns in the root anyways

Comment: Ah, now I understand. For any standard conformal XML parser it doesn't matter whether a namespace is declared on the root element of the document or any path until it is used. For this reason JAXB won't have a possibility to change its behaviour. So either you are confronted with a none conformal XML parser/validator or the problem might be some other (e.g. namespaces of the parent elements). Couldn't you get the XML-schema from the third party application?

Comment: Yes, I generated the JAXB classes automatically starting from the schema provided by them. Unfortunately, when I marshal the objects all the namespaces go on top

Comment: See my edit. I can't imaging that a standard conformal XML parser insists to have the namespaces on a child element .